# My SVG appears to have data, but it isn't rendering

Tags: html, svg

I'm not particularly clear on the ins and outs of rendering svg in html. I have loaded an svg file via [`svg-inline-loader`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/svg-inline-loader), and the data appears to be present, but nothing is rendering. I imagine I'm missing something rather basic here, but  I can't see what, and I haven't been able to find any resources on what may cause this.

```html
<svg xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd" xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape" version="1.0" viewBox="0 0 306.000000 599.000000" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" id="svg3755" sodipodi:docname="car.svg" inkscape:version="0.92.3 (2405546, 2018-03-11)"><defs id="defs3759"></defs><sodipodi:namedview pagecolor="#ffffff" bordercolor="#666666" borderopacity="1" objecttolerance="10" gridtolerance="10" guidetolerance="10" inkscape:pageopacity="0" inkscape:pageshadow="2" inkscape:window-width="1920" inkscape:window-height="1017" id="namedview3757" showgrid="false" inkscape:zoom="1.501569" inkscape:cx="133.29366" inkscape:cy="404.34747" inkscape:window-x="1912" inkscape:window-y="-8" inkscape:window-maximized="1" inkscape:current-layer="g3753"><metadata id="metadata3737"> Created by potrace 1.15, written by Peter Selinger 2001-2017 <rdf:rdf><cc:work rdf:about=""><dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format><dc:type rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage"><dc:title></dc:title></dc:type></cc:work></rdf:rdf></metadata><g transform="matrix(0.1,0,0,-0.1,3,599)" id="g3753" style="fill:#000000;stroke:#000000"><path d="M 1310,5984 C 1097,5959 960,5927 828,5870 592,5769 410,5601 303,5385 213,5205 181,5053 173,4770 c -6,-222 6,-337 47,-440 18,-47 20,-74 20,-354 v -303 l -84,-33 C 44,3597 0,3549 0,3470 c 0,-27 37,-140 45,-140 2,0 41,9 87,20 46,11 89,20 97,20 22,0 9,-986 -18,-1370 C 168,1397 171,1170 226,850 260,651 342,316 386,194 418,105 550,58 870,18 1017,0 1983,0 2130,18 c 320,40 452,87 484,176 44,122 126,457 160,656 55,320 58,547 15,1150 -27,384 -40,1370 -18,1370 8,0 51,-9 97,-20 46,-11 85,-20 87,-20 8,0 45,113 45,140 0,79 -44,127 -156,170 l -84,33 v 303 c 0,280 2,307 20,354 41,103 53,218 47,440 -8,283 -40,435 -130,615 -154,311 -451,511 -862,581 -86,15 -448,27 -525,18 z m 418,-74 c 114,-12 227,-35 312,-63 64,-22 65,-23 76,-67 38,-153 150,-238 344,-260 68,-8 78,-12 102,-41 76,-91 155,-302 183,-491 31,-204 16,-525 -29,-633 -14,-32 -18,-100 -23,-382 l -6,-343 34,-14 c 177,-72 187,-78 198,-102 6,-14 11,-37 11,-52 0,-53 -8,-55 -121,-27 -57,14 -108,25 -113,25 -4,0 -6,-248 -3,-552 4,-452 10,-629 32,-968 47,-728 27,-979 -120,-1535 -25,-93 -49,-180 -55,-192 C 2511,122 2083,60 1500,60 917,60 489,122 450,213 c -6,12 -30,99 -55,192 -147,556 -167,807 -120,1535 22,339 28,516 32,968 3,304 1,552 -3,552 -5,0 -56,-11 -113,-25 -113,-28 -121,-26 -121,27 0,15 5,38 11,52 11,24 21,30 198,102 l 34,14 -6,343 c -5,282 -9,350 -23,382 -45,108 -60,429 -29,633 28,189 107,400 183,491 24,29 34,33 102,41 194,22 306,107 344,260 11,44 12,45 76,67 79,26 207,53 304,63 106,11 358,11 464,0 z" id="path3739" inkscape:connector-curvature="0"></path><path d="m 1290,4498 c -343,-35 -617,-174 -711,-359 -49,-98 -49,-154 0,-409 58,-300 103,-388 216,-419 56,-15 1354,-15 1410,0 113,31 158,119 216,419 49,255 49,311 0,409 -133,262 -610,414 -1131,359 z" id="path3743" inkscape:connector-curvature="0"></path><path d="m 445,2748 c 2,-940 0,-912 59,-1026 32,-60 60,-92 115,-131 33,-23 47,-28 52,-19 21,40 38,555 28,819 -17,422 -71,764 -165,1041 -39,115 -67,178 -79,178 -9,0 -11,-223 -10,-862 z" id="path3745" inkscape:connector-curvature="0"></path><path d="m 2512,3558 c -122,-296 -192,-682 -211,-1167 -10,-264 7,-779 28,-819 5,-9 19,-4 52,19 55,39 83,71 115,131 59,114 57,86 59,1026 1,639 -1,862 -10,862 -6,0 -21,-24 -33,-52 z" id="path3747" inkscape:connector-curvature="0"></path><path d="m 842,1453 c -41,-20 -69,-54 -83,-103 -10,-32 -5,-78 31,-301 23,-145 49,-277 57,-292 80,-155 359,-271 653,-271 294,0 573,116 654,271 8,16 33,148 57,295 42,265 42,267 25,313 -11,27 -32,56 -54,73 l -35,27 -636,2 c -572,3 -639,1 -669,-14 z" id="path3749" inkscape:connector-curvature="0"></path></g></sodipodi:namedview></svg>
```

Comment: Everything is inside sodipodi:namedview and SVG does not render the contents of unknown elements so you might see something in inkscape but nowhere else.

Comment: Jeez, are all the namespaces necessary? Seems like a lot of unnecessary bloat to include everything from dublin core to inkscape to cc and everything in between? Leaves a lot of room for compatibility nightmares imo.

Comment: @ChrisW. I'm guessing that it isn't necessary, as I say I'm no expert on the way SVG's work, which is partly why I'm asking for help here

Comment: @OliverRadini No worries, glad you found a remedy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When something like this is happening I try to manually edit the svg. I'm not very sure this is answering your question, but in case you need to use the svg:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 3000 6000"> <g id="g3753" style="fill:#000000;stroke:#000000"><path d="M 1310,5984 C 1097,5959 960,5927 828,5870 592,5769 410,5601 303,5385 213,5205 181,5053 173,4770 c -6,-222 6,-337 47,-440 18,-47 20,-74 20,-354 v -303 l -84,-33 C 44,3597 0,3549 0,3470 c 0,-27 37,-140 45,-140 2,0 41,9 87,20 46,11 89,20 97,20 22,0 9,-986 -18,-1370 C 168,1397 171,1170 226,850 260,651 342,316 386,194 418,105 550,58 870,18 1017,0 1983,0 2130,18 c 320,40 452,87 484,176 44,122 126,457 160,656 55,320 58,547 15,1150 -27,384 -40,1370 -18,1370 8,0 51,-9 97,-20 46,-11 85,-20 87,-20 8,0 45,113 45,140 0,79 -44,127 -156,170 l -84,33 v 303 c 0,280 2,307 20,354 41,103 53,218 47,440 -8,283 -40,435 -130,615 -154,311 -451,511 -862,581 -86,15 -448,27 -525,18 z m 418,-74 c 114,-12 227,-35 312,-63 64,-22 65,-23 76,-67 38,-153 150,-238 344,-260 68,-8 78,-12 102,-41 76,-91 155,-302 183,-491 31,-204 16,-525 -29,-633 -14,-32 -18,-100 -23,-382 l -6,-343 34,-14 c 177,-72 187,-78 198,-102 6,-14 11,-37 11,-52 0,-53 -8,-55 -121,-27 -57,14 -108,25 -113,25 -4,0 -6,-248 -3,-552 4,-452 10,-629 32,-968 47,-728 27,-979 -120,-1535 -25,-93 -49,-180 -55,-192 C 2511,122 2083,60 1500,60 917,60 489,122 450,213 c -6,12 -30,99 -55,192 -147,556 -167,807 -120,1535 22,339 28,516 32,968 3,304 1,552 -3,552 -5,0 -56,-11 -113,-25 -113,-28 -121,-26 -121,27 0,15 5,38 11,52 11,24 21,30 198,102 l 34,14 -6,343 c -5,282 -9,350 -23,382 -45,108 -60,429 -29,633 28,189 107,400 183,491 24,29 34,33 102,41 194,22 306,107 344,260 11,44 12,45 76,67 79,26 207,53 304,63 106,11 358,11 464,0 z" id="path3739" ></path><path d="m 1290,4498 c -343,-35 -617,-174 -711,-359 -49,-98 -49,-154 0,-409 58,-300 103,-388 216,-419 56,-15 1354,-15 1410,0 113,31 158,119 216,419 49,255 49,311 0,409 -133,262 -610,414 -1131,359 z" id="path3743" ></path><path d="m 445,2748 c 2,-940 0,-912 59,-1026 32,-60 60,-92 115,-131 33,-23 47,-28 52,-19 21,40 38,555 28,819 -17,422 -71,764 -165,1041 -39,115 -67,178 -79,178 -9,0 -11,-223 -10,-862 z" id="path3745" ></path><path d="m 2512,3558 c -122,-296 -192,-682 -211,-1167 -10,-264 7,-779 28,-819 5,-9 19,-4 52,19 55,39 83,71 115,131 59,114 57,86 59,1026 1,639 -1,862 -10,862 -6,0 -21,-24 -33,-52 z" id="path3747" ></path><path d="m 842,1453 c -41,-20 -69,-54 -83,-103 -10,-32 -5,-78 31,-301 23,-145 49,-277 57,-292 80,-155 359,-271 653,-271 294,0 573,116 654,271 8,16 33,148 57,295 42,265 42,267 25,313 -11,27 -32,56 -54,73 l -35,27 -636,2 c -572,3 -639,1 -669,-14 z" id="path3749"></path></g></svg>
```

Comment: That's excellent, thanks! This is ideal and solves my problem perfectly. I had generated this by running it through converters which probably explains all the additional stuff which is not needed